# Changing integers in classes C++

Tags: c++

Okay, so, I am storing a public integer in a class, like this:

```
class varglobalness{
    public:

    int xp;
    int lvl;
    int xpt;
    int hp;

};
```

and, inside of a function I am trying to change the variables by doing this:

```
v.lvl += 1;
v.xpt += rand()%25+25;
v.xp = 0;
v.hp += rand()%25+5;
```

When I do this, though, hp doesn't change, xp does change to 0, but xpt and lvl changes to a lot of random numbers.

Any idea how I can properly change these integers without this happening?

Comment: Can you give some complete, compilable code that demonstrates the problem?  And what does "inside of a void" mean?  (I have mental images of being in a cave...)

Comment: You get random numbers because you assign random numbers.....

Comment: @Tomalak - *What is "a void"?* - Maybe he's trying to do it in space? :P

Comment: Amazing what people end up coding when they don't understand the most basic mechanics of it.

Comment: He means a function.  He's getting confused by the syntax `void functionName()`

Comment: @BlueRaja: I was hoping that _he_ would answer the question and come to that conclusion on his own.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm guessing a (member?) function that returns `void`.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Be a little more forgiving - there's a lot of new terminology to learn when learning how to program, not everyone can absorb all of it at once.

Comment: @BlueRaja: I'm not saying that he can. The idea is that he should think about my question and come to the solution, learning something in the process. Of course that's all null and _void_ now that y'all have just gone and spat out the answer for him!

Comment: @Tomalak:  Terminology isn't something you can just sit down, think about, and come to the correct answer on your own; either you know it, or you don't.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Bullcrap. How do you think the people that "know it" ended up with that knowledge? From birth? We all moved from unknowns to knowns.And how? By reasoning on the questions and on what they don't know and reach to the resources at hand. It is perfectly reasonable to believe Pebsie is using a textbook (or at worse, some online tutorial). Somewhere in the reading he/needs to do there is sufficient explanation about "the void". Or are we to believe he/she doesn't have any reference at his/her disposal to read? Spoonfeeding will never help new learners to cross that analytical chasm.

Comment: @BlueRaja - con't. in other words, you are not helping him/her. His instructor, if he has any, talked about functions and returns values. His textbook, or whatever he's using certainly is using that. If he has neither, the question is moot and all of this is a waste of mental effort. Assuming it is not, then *"what is a void"* is the best way to get this person to think in the way he needs to be successful at this (and not be yet one more cookie cutter code monkey who cannot find his way out of a for loop.) And more importantly, as Voltaire once said, he'll clarify his terms.

Comment: @BlueRaja - con't. A good instructor (or instruction method) never spoonfeeds. He answer questions with additional inquiries, to elicit an analytical feedback loop between him and the person asking the question. It is neither unreasonable, nor cruel, to do so. Assuming otherwise is to assume programming (or anything sufficiently complex) can be learned by literal dictation alone.

Comment: @luis: Terminology is not something you can just figure out, because it's arbitrary - it has to be taught.  Algorithms, problem-solving, mathematics.. these are things the students can figure out on their own (with a bit of help, of course).  But *"we call that thing a function, not a void"* is a matter of being told by someone - it could be called anything at all, for all he knows, and the only way for him to find out is to be told by someone (whether me, or a book, or a webpage, or whatever).

Comment: @BlueRaja - *But "we call that thing a function, not a void" is a matter of being told by someone* - can you reasonably believe that this person, who comes here with a programming question and, ergo, is most likely taking a programming course or learning from a programming book **has not been told already** (or read from a book or online source) that *this* thing *is a function that returns void* as opposed to being called *a void* **already**?  That. Is. A. Very. Weak. Argument.

Comment: @BlueRaja - more to the point, do you honestly believe that a person that comes here asking for questions on how to change fields DEFINED BY A CLASS (all the while using `rand()` of all things!) has not come across **at least once** (and most likely repeatedly) with explanations and nomenclatures on functions and return types? Either in lecture notes or self-study materials, things that one should refer to (you know, *read*) as part of the learning process? And assuming this unlikely event happens to be the case, do you think spoonfeeding will actually help this person become a programmer?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're not properly initialising them. If a variable is uninitialised, it'll have an undefined value. You can give them initial values in the constructor:

```
// varglobalness.h:
class varglobalness {
public:

    varglobalness();

    // ...

};

// varglobalness.cpp:
varglobalness::varglobalness() : xp(0), lvl(0), xpt(0), hp(0) {}
```

Or assign them initial values elsewhere, as you prefer. As an aside, you ought to be putting these variables somewhere meaningful and encapsulated, rather than in a bundle of random globals.

Comment: Using this, I get an error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token

Comment: @Pebsie: Edited to give more detail on how to set things up properly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you initialize the variables?  Variables in C++ don't initialize themselves.

```
//In your constructor
v.lvl = 1;
v.xpt = 0;
v.xp = 0;
v.hp = 0;
```

Comment: Did you miss the part of the question where he assigns values to all four?

Comment: @Tomalak:  He doesn't.  The ones he's having problems with use `+=`

Comment: varglobalness v; v.xp = 0; v.lvl = 1; v.xpt = 50; v.hp = 25;